# Android tv : Webview for each item in header fragment

Tags: android-webview, android-tv, leanback

I want to show a separate webview when clicked on any header item; using BrowseSupportFragment for this purpose. But all the examples I have seen binds row of grids to each header item.

Please guide me how to bind webview to each item in header fragment.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

[PageAndListRowFragment.java](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/blob/master/LeanbackShowcase/app/src/main/java/androidx/leanback/leanbackshowcase/app/page/PageAndListRowFragment.java)